# How to change initial indentation level in CoffeeScript block string while dynamically generating .coffee files?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm using coffeescript to generate .coffee files.

Here is the example of the code I'm using ([JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Shtirlits/drfvme6x/), so you can play with it). It is heavily simplified, just so you can understand the idea. Each method will have it's own code, and each file will have it's own methods.

```
input = [
    name: 'method1'
  ,
    name: 'method2'
  ,
    name: 'method3'
]

Class = """
  Base = require './base'

  class ClassName extends Base
    option1: 1
    option2: 2


"""

for method, i in input
  Class += """

    #{method.name}: (cb) ->
      console.log #{i}


  """
```

As output I get

```
Base = require './base'

class ClassName extends Base
  option1: 1
  option2: 2

method1: (cb) ->
  console.log 0

method2: (cb) ->
  console.log 1

method3: (cb) ->
  console.log 2
```

which is obviously not what I need, because methods aren't indented appropriately, and CoffeeScript relies on indentation.

So the question is - what should I do to make the output have proper indentation?

**P.S.** If you think I'm doing it (generating .coffee files) wrong - please, feel free to tell how it should be done in proper way.

Comment: Have you considered using a real template system instead of manual string wrangling?

Comment: @muistooshort I wasn't able to find one for coffeescript. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Text is text even if it the text is CoffeeScript code. Template libraries deal with text.